# Labels and tooltips on plotbands highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I've created gauge chart and now I'm trying to figure out how to put yAxis labels exactly at the ends of plotbands and how to make tooltips for the bands.

Here is my chart so far: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aTVs/3/)

I could not find how to create plotband tooltip with regular tooltip object, so I use moseenter avent to show tooltip.

```
events: {
                    mouseenter: function(e) {
                        $('#tooltipholder').html('You are hovering yellow plotband, get ready!');
                        console.log('mouseenter');
                    },
                    mouseleave: function() {
                        $('#tooltipholder').html('');
                    }
                },
```

It's not a tooltip, but it's the best I could achieve so far.

So no my problems are:

**1. Have now ideas how to put labels at the end of plotbands.**

**2. May be there is a way to put tooltip on plotband.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To set labels at the end of plotBands use `tickPositions`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/7aTVs/4/
2. PlotBands doesn't support tooltip. Your solution looks properly. Just make div positioned absolutely and use `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` to set left/top position in CSS.

Comment: They are just values where tick with label should be displayed :)